# Timeout error itgenerr024 when trying to import data from Exact Online into Microsoft Excel with Invantive Control

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control, exact-online

When I execute the query I get the following error after ten minutes:

```
Error processing file 'c:\temp\in\GLTransactions\070-GLTransactions-2016-9-4-102.xml':Invantive.Data.OAuthException: itgenerr024: Your session has expired.
Please log on again. 
at Invantive.Data.ExactOnlineProvider.InterpreteResults(List'1SubproviderResults) in File294:line 609 
at Invantive.Data.ExactOnlineProvider.ExecuteAction(String action, ParameterList paramters, Int32& result) in File294:line 727
at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteProviderAction(String action, ParameterList parameters, String& handlingPath) in File39:line 2685
at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteAction(String action, ParameterList parameters) in File39:line 1761
at
Invantive.Producer.Windows.Forms.LocalQueryProcessor.ProcessClientSideStatement
(Object owner, IProgressNotifier notifier, String statement, ultrGrid resultsGrid, ResultSet, 
Dictionary'2 resultSetClipBoards, DisplayColumnDefinitionCollection scriptingFieldDisplayDefaults, 
Action'1 fetchMoreRows, Action'7 executeStatement, String
lastServerStatementExecutedWithoutExpansion, String lastServerStatementExecuted, ParameterList
bindVariables, Boolean showResultsInGrid, Boolean showStatistics, Boolean
memorizeStatisticsInSqlHistory, Boolean allowPaging, Boolean&exitApplication) in File387:line 2284
```

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please note that when uploading data into Exact Online, there is a short-lived token involved which lasts 10 minutes. Refreshing it is not always working. You might want to try to put a 'local log on' before the statement that imports the data. This gives you more time to upload the data.

Answer (score 0):

On uploading data into Exact Online, there is a short-lived token which lasts 10 minutes. If you edit the queries during that time or the queries take longer than 10 minutes, it will expire. On some combinations of databases such as Exact Online only connections it will automatically renew the short-lived token (OAuth).

On some combinations, as with SQL Server/Oracle/Freshdesk and Exact Online open, this does not yet work; you will need to reconnect to get another token. This will be supported starting the Christmas release.

As a workaround, you can reconnect by adding the following code before the `local eol xml import`:

```
local log on
```

This one will ask for your credentials using the GUI or text mode form. Or even more extensive:

```
local log on [connection \"<CONNECTIONNAME>\"] [user \"<LOGONCODE>\"] [password \"<PASSWORD>\"] [encryptedpassword \"<ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD>\"] [silent]
```

Where you replace `<CONNECTIONNAME>` by the group name and database name such as `Exact Online\Exact Online (uk)`, `<LOGONCODE>` by your log on code for the database, `<PASSWORD>` by the password in plain text (not recommended!) or better the encrypted password in `<ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD>`. The encrypted password must have been encrypted using the device key with `local encrypt password` on the device itself.

Or the silent version (less logging):

```
local log on connection \"<CONNECTIONNAME>\" user \"<LOGONCODE>\" encryptedpassword \"<ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD>\" silent
```

Does this fix it for you?